# Return Token Contract address on truffle deploy

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, addresses, truffle-migration

I am trying to figure out how to return the address of a contract when I deploy it with truffle's deployer.deploy.  So the goal is that when I deploy a contract that is a custom token, I want to return that address once it's deployed and pass that address to my CrowdSale contract constructor.  I am getting undefined for the instance of the deployed contract when doing this like so:

1_initial_migration.js

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(CrowdTestToken).then((instance) => {
    console.log(instance);
    deployer.deploy(CrowdSale, instance.address);
  });
};
```

In the above example, instance is undefined.  Does anybody know how I can get the address of the CrowdTestToken contract in the deployment script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The address of the contract is just the variable name of the deployed contract.
Try this:

```
deployer.deploy(CrowdTestToken).then(function(){
    return deployer.deploy(CrowdSale, CrowdTestToken.address)});
```